# Does the Intersection of Images imply an Injective Function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I've read that $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ is true iff $f$ is an injective function' (and thus the statement is biconditional), and I've been trying to understand why this is true, but struggling.

I understand from the proofs the implication that if $f$ **is injective** $\implies f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ . But it's the reverse implication I'm struggling with, as I seem to be finding counter examples; where am I going wrong?

Let $f$ be a function s.t. $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$. Clearly, if $x\in (A \cap B)\implies f(x) \in  ( f(A) \cap f(B) )$.

But for some functions, couldn't there also be a set $C \neq (A \cup B)$ such that $f(C) = f(A) \cap f(B)$? And hence, $f$ would be a many-one function, despite $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$?

**Example:**

Consider the domain $D = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$ and the codomain $E = \{a, b\}$ and a function $f$ that maps $D$ to $E$ s.t. odd numbers in $D$ map to a and even numbers map to b.

Now, let the sets $A$, $B$, $C$ $\subset$ $D$ equal $\{1, 2\}$ and $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and $\{5, 6\}$ respectively. Then, $(A \cap B) = \{1, 2\}$ and $f(A) \cap f(B) = \{a, b\} = f(A \cap B)$.

But clearly now, $f(C) = \{a, b\} = f(A) \cap f(B)$ - the equality holds, but $f$ is many-one, not injective.

I must be wrong in my logic somewhere/not understood some basic facts about sets and their equality, but can't see what? Any thoughts?

Thanks very much, indeed.

Comment: The statement as written is incorrect. I think one direction asks that it is true for all subsets of the domain (not sure though)

Comment: Thanks @Math_QED, I see now how I misunderstood the original statement I read. The equality must be true for **every** pair of subsets of the domain, not just two in particular (which is what I was thinking without realising), in order for the function to be injective (and thus for the statement to be biconditional). Thanks again.

Comment: Always glad if I can help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that for each subsets $A$ and $B$ of the domain of $f$, it is true that $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$. You want to deduce from this that $f$ is injective. Let $x$ and $y$ be distinct elements of the domain of $f$; you want to prove that $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Since $x\neq y$, $\{x\}\cap\{y\}=\emptyset$, and therefore$$f(\{x\})\cap f(\{y\})=f(\{x\}\cap\{y\})=\emptyset.$$But$$f(\{x\})\cap f(\{y\})=\bigl\{f(x)\bigr\}\cap\bigl\{f(y)\bigr\}$$and saying that this set is empty means precisely that $f(x)\neq f(y)$.

Comment: I think your use of the word 'each' at the start of your answer alone sparked in my mind where I went wrong. Many thanks! Basically, I misunderstood the original statement. In the counterexample I gave, the equality was true for 2 /particular/ subsets of D, and yet (as demonstrated by C) f was a many-one function. But I understand now that the equality in the original biconditional statement is strictly true for /every/ pair of subsets of D. And thus my example wasn't a relevant counterexample, hence why I was tripping over it.

Your full explanation of course proves the implication. Thanks!

Comment: Sorted, thanks again.